# Cartpole problem: Too many values to unpack (expected 4)

Tags: python, reinforcement-learning

The code for the classic reinforcement learning Cartpole problem throws up an error:

> ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 4)

when the following code is used:

```
    # Take action and observe next state and reward
    next_state, reward, done, info = env.step(action)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you are using gymnasium.

env.step returns five values, not four. https://gymnasium.farama.org/api/env/#gymnasium.Env.step

```
next_state, reward, truncated, terminated, info = env.step(action)
```

Comment: That works but then it throws up another error: IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices

Comment: The above errow derived from this line of code:  ```Q[state, action] = (1 - alpha) * Q[state, action] + alpha * (reward + gamma * np.max(Q[next_state, :])) ```